# Header Key Cookies and Referer got response 401

Tags: node.js, axios, xmlhttprequest

I tried to call external API in my API server with axios and it worked. this is the code

```
const result = await axios.get(
  `http://external-api-url-here.com/example-endpoint/xyz`,
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "App-key": 'ExAmPl3_KeY-H3r3',
      "key-platform": 'admin-desktop',
    },
  }
);
```

but the problem is when I try the code in my web client application, when it runs in the browser and tries to make a request with the code it doesn't work, getting a 307 response.

Then I added `withCredentials: true` in the axios header. getting a 401 response,

then I copied cURL from the browser and imported it into postman and it turned out that what made the API response fail was `Cookies` and `Referer`. When I remove those 2 key headers from postman, I get response 200.

what is the solution for this?

I want to that code get response 200 at the browser